# SQLite rawQuery from BuildUnionQuery Selecting just the first true condition

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following code in Android Studio

```
String[] buildquery={
            "SELECT anatomia FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE anatomia='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT bioquimica FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE bioquimica='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT histologia FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE histologia='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT fisiologia FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE fisiologia='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT embriologia FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE embriologia='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT microbiologia FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE microbiologia='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT urgencias FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE urgencias='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT farmacologia FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE farmacologia='si';",
            "SELECT nutricion FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE nutricion='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT patologia FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE patologia='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';",
            "SELECT fisiopatologia FROM "+usuariosinfodbh.tablausuarioname+" WHERE fisiopatologia='si' AND usuario='"+nombre+"';"
    };
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb=new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String query=qb.buildUnionQuery(buildquery, null, null);
    Cursor c= db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

When I run this with the pertinent Log.d to know how many columns are being selected, it shows me only 1, which is the first column where the condition is met (which is anatomia='si' in this case). I know it is the first one becase if I remove the SELECT... where anatomia='si', then it the Log.d prints nutricion='si', which is the next condition that is true.
I want this code to select ALL the columns where the condition I set is fullfilled, not just the first that meets it.
Thank you in advance.
PS: (Log.d)s I'm using are:

```
Log.d("countcolumsreg", Integer.toString(c.getCount()));//0
    Log.d("countcolumns", Integer.toString(c.getColumnCount()));//0
```

and

```
String[] usuariomaterias= new String[c.getColumnCount()];    
for (int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount();i++) {
        usuariomaterias[i] = c.getColumnName(i);
        Log.d("arrayseg",usuariomaterias[i]); //anatomia
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what a `UNION` does: it performs a bunch of queries, and merges the results from each into one result set. When using `UNION` without the `ALL` modifier, duplicate rows are removed. This is why you're getting only one row -- all your matching rows simply contain `'si'`, so they're all duplicates.

Side note: to prevent SQL injection attacks, you should always use queries with `?` placeholders, supplying the arguments in a separate value array (the second argument, `selectionArgs`, in the case of `rawQuery()`).

I'm not sure, but it seems like you want to know whether there is a 'si' in each column. Here's an alternative that gives you a TRUE/FALSE for each:

```
SELECT
  anatomia='si' AS anatomia,
  bioquimica='si' AS bioquimica,
  histologia='si' AS histologia,
  ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE usuario=?
```

This will give you a result that looks something like:

```
anatomia bioquimica histologia ...
       1          0          1 ...
```

However, maybe you should consider changing your table design to make the columns `BOOLEAN` instead -- because 'si' really sounds like a boolean value. That way, you can essentially do `SELECT * FROM...` or at least `SELECT anatomia, bioquimica, histologia... FROM...` instead, making your code much prettier. :)

**Update after @LuisE replied with a comment:**

There isn't really a convenient way to treat columns as "data" in SQL. The best option I can come up with is (assuming we've made the change from 'si' to actual boolean values):

```
SELECT 'anatomia' FROM yourtable WHERE usuario=?1 AND anatomia
UNION SELECT 'bioquimica' FROM yourtable WHERE usuario=?1 AND bioquimica
UNION SELECT 'histologia' FROM yourtable WHERE usuario=?1 AND histologia
...
```

But as you can see, that still requires a bunch of very similar SELECTs. Not very pretty.

BTW, through all this, I'm assuming that usuario is unique (either as a `PRIMARY KEY` or just `UNIQUE`).